# Как можно реализовать подобную вещь ? Js

Tags: javascript, эффекты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу нигде найти, как называется данный эффект.

Comment: не понятно что Вам надо получить

Comment: scrollspy наверн

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это навигация по сайту

Comment: а эффект тотв чем заключается?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вот я хз как обьяснить, короче скролишь вниз меняется блок подсвечивается вторая точка и тд

Comment: на svg можно такое нарисовать, вечерком нарисую, если не ответят

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Называется такой эффект scrollspy

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elems = $('.scrollspy');
    elems.each(function(index){
      var elemTop  = $(this).offset().top;
      var elemBottom  = elemTop + $(this).height();
      if(currentTop >= elemTop && currentTop <= elemBottom){
        var id   = $(this).attr('id');
        var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id+ '"]');
    navElem.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass( 'active' );
      }
    })
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

#nav{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:50%;
}

section{
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-template">
        <div class="row col-xs-12 text-center">
          <ul>
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#AboutUs">AboutUs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Images">Images</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <section class="scrollspy" id="Home">
      Home
      </section>

      <section class="scrollspy" id="AboutUs">
      AboutUs
      </section>

      <section class="scrollspy" id="Images">
      Images
      </section>

      <section class="scrollspy" id="Contact">
      Contact
      </section>
```

Comment: Вот так вот, помогаешь людям а они дизлайки лупят(((

Comment: Спасибо большое реально помог)